# How can I run a project in Python 2.7 and with all required former versions of dependencies without messing up with my computer's set up?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to run a github project on my computer, the project is written in Python 2.7 (I would rather not convert to Python 3.5 manually because of the size etc). I can not run it with 2.7 because I need older versions of some dependencies (tensorflow etc.). How can I run a project in Python 2.7 and with all required former versions of dependencies without messing up with my computer's set up? (I need to keep it stable for my project). The last time I did it, I had some trouble re-running my projects and also I had to convert back everything. Is this why people work on virtual environments? Can I set up a quick one for now without getting in too much detail? Recommendations welcome.

Comment: That is exactly what virtualenv is for.

Comment: Thanks, I am now looking into it, can you recommend a good source for a quick start? (for Ubuntu)

Comment: Now I am running virtualenv with Python 2.7 but getting everything else in their former versions one by one is very challenging, in fact I failed to get an older version of pytorch working, and I wasn't sure which one it should be as the project didn't specify it. Is there a better way?